# how to add ReadMore in paragraph

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, laravel

I have a controller for homepage which gives `$posts` var which includes that post title and body and sometimes there may be a large amount of text in the body

```
return view('posts.index',compact('posts'));
```

and I want to hide all paragraph text and add a button called ReadMore which shows full paragraph
I saw the following bootstrap examples

```js
function myFunction() {
  var dots = document.getElementById("dots");
  var moreText = document.getElementById("more");
  var btnText = document.getElementById("myBtn");

  if (dots.style.display === "none") {
    dots.style.display = "inline";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read more";
    moreText.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    dots.style.display = "none";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read less";
    moreText.style.display = "inline";
  }
}
```

```html
<h2>Read More Read Less Button</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas vitae scel<span id="dots">...</span><span id="more">erisque enim nibh tempor porta.</span></p>
<button onclick="myFunction()" id="myBtn">Read more</button>
```

in the above example text there is span id in middle and here I don't know how do I add that span between `$post->body` data. is there any way to make a ReadMore and ShowLess feature?
I am currently showing data as

```
<p>{!!$post->body!!} </p>
```

Comment: Are you wanting a way to do this in php or javascript?

Comment: @RossWilson thankyou for your question :-) i was willing to do it in best possible way, i followed the laravel docs in string handling functions and i tried below suggestion as well and both solved the issue.i hope this post might help someone in future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like given below code:

```
{{ substr( $post->body, 0, random_int(60, 150)) }}
```

And for **read more** you can link the single article in anchor tag:

```
<a href="/post/{{ $post->id }}">Read more </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a CSS approach. You can set a CSS class to style it as an truncated text (when the max height exceeded with long text):

```
.post .post-short-description {
    height: 36px;
    display: -webkit-box;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 2;            /* How many lines before truncated */       
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}
```

In your **view.blade.php**:

```
@php
    $hasLongBody = strlen($p->body) >= 150;
@endPhp

<div class="post">
  <h3> {{ $p->title }} </h3>
  <p class="post-short-description"> {{ $p->body }} </p>
  <a href="{{ route('postDetail', $p->id) }}" @class([
      'd-none' => !$hasLongBody 
  ])> Readmore </a>
</div>
```